How do I change the clipboard provider at runtime?
I run most of my nvim sessions inside of tmux sessions so they persist across logins.  If I log out from x11 and log into a wayland session, then I can still reconnect to my tmux and nvim sessions.  But the clipboard that nvim is configured to use xclip based on the environment variables nvim was started with.
I wrote some lua code to change the vim.g.clipboard global variable via a user command.  I've confirmed that it's effectively changing the global variable but "+y is still using xclip.  Why?
Example:
:ClipboardWayland
:lua vim.print(vim.g.clipboard)
{
    name = "wl-copy",
    copy = {
        ["+"] = { "wl-copy", "-" },
        ["*"] = { "wl-copy", "-" },
    },
    paste = {
        ["+"] = { "wl-paste", "-" },
        ["*"] = { "wl-paste", "-" },
    },
    cache_enabled = 1,
}

But running "+y still gives me errors from xclip instead of errors from wl-copy.  I know I still need to update environment variables to get wl-copy to work, but it should be using wl-copy now that vim.g.clipboard is defined as wl-copy.  Why is it not?

Only setting g:clipboard variable has no effect. You must run script to apply changes (basically, it validates g:clipboard value and copies it into another internal dictionary).
vim.g.clipboard = {...}
vim.g.loaded_clipboard_provider = nil
vim.cmd"runtime autoload/provider/clipboard.vim"

See :h provider-reload. Also, in :h faq.
